# Query not displaying all results from MySQL database

Tags: php, mysql

bit confused here with what's wrong with my query. I have about 9 records and am trying to get all this 9 records from MySQL database. The weird thing happening is only 2 of the records are coming out and I really don't understand what's going on as my query seems to be Ok.

```
$mQ = "SELECT * FROM group_elective_modules 
        WHERE group_elective_modules.yr = '4' 
        AND 
        group_elective_modules.courseName = 'BSCSHCSSEntrepreneurship' ";
$mR = mysql_query($mQ);
while ($ROW = mysql_fetch_array($mR)) {                                                                 
    echo $ROW['moduleID'] . "&nbsp;&nbsp;". $ROW['yr'] . "<BR />";
}
```

Here's the table [image]

Any help would be appreciated as I don't understand what's going on with this query. Thanks in advance.

Comment: "I have about 9 records" Prove it.

Comment: Can you provide some sample data?  There may be a simple typo in `courseName` for example in some records (such as extra spaces at the beginning or end) or your records just don't match your criteria.

Comment: It would be helpful to see the data

Comment: I'm guessing that the other records have a `yr != 4`…

Comment: try the select * version (with no where clause) and check each column

Comment: @IgnacioVazquez-Abrams At a scale of millions, 2 is indeed "about 9". :-)

Comment: Additionaly, if your're getting raw text, before placing it in your DOM you should escape it. For example using `htmlentities()`...

Comment: Have you tried running that same query straight in the database?

Comment: @ andrewsi Actually that's a good idea,run the query straight in the database. I'll give that a go. Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Look if there are spaces in the entries, so you could trim before with TRIM(var) = 'value_without_spaces'

FYI, No need to put "group_elective_modules." appendix in yr and courseName vars

Comment: @ user1352530 ..Thanks.It was the space!

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if this matters but is year a string or number? Also try just querying for year and see if the results are correct.

Comment: @ Alex Reynolds..Year is a number.I fixed it. Figured out there was some sort of space in `courseName`. Thanks for the suggestion.